# What type of dirt do I need to fix holes in my driveway

Tags: driveway, landscaping

I apologize for this being a very basic question.  I have several holes and low spots in my dirt driveway (see picture below).  I want to fix it in the upcoming spring but I do not know what i would use or where I would go to get it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yellow pages (the paper kind may still be best for this, or an internet equivalent that actually groks "local" results), **gravel**, **stone** (headings.)

Crushed rock with fines (sometimes called "road pack") - you want all the fine dust so that it will pack and stay put, rather than only loose rocks that will move around. Depending on the supply in your local area this may be gravel that has been run through a crusher to reduce the big rocks to smaller ones, (crusher run, or various sifted grades such as "one inch minus" or "one and a half inch minus") or actual quarried stone that has been similarly crushed from much larger pieces.

If you find the right sort of vendor, you can simply explain what you are doing and they will know what to bring.

Answer (score 1):

Using a shovel (not a spade) scrape existing dirt from along the grassy edge of the driveway (to help form a shallow drainage ditch while getting the dirt needed).

Put this dirt in low spots until they become high spots of 1"-2".

Repeat after compacting with a tamper or rolling a vehicle over it a couple time.

If future low spots develop, just repeat above while developing a nice, shallow drainage along the entire perimeter of driveway.

BTW, there should be a crown (ridge) along the central axis of the driveway that's sloped about 1" for every 3'0" from crown to edge...just like a roadway.